# I cannot get .htaccess rewrite rule to work with my Prestashop site

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, prestashop

Okay, I used an automated generator to generate a custom URL for my prestashop site in the .htaccess file, but it does not work. Any ideas?

the original URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/de/suche?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=mutter&submit_search=OK
```

the rewritten url should be:

```
http://www.example.com/search/position/desc/mutter/OK.html
```

and the rewrite rule I have in the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /de/suche?controller=$1&orderby=$2&orderway=$3&search_query=$4&submit_search=$5 [L]
```

Comment: The rule you have looks OK. Define "not work". Is the rewrite engine enabled? Other directives in .htaccess?

Comment: Hey thank you, yes the rewrite engine is on, and there are a bunch of other directives (all standard prestashop stuff)

What I mean by "not work" is a a 404 not found error instead of actual redirect. 

Did this help?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an _internal rewrite_, not an _external redirect_, so you won't actually _see_ any change in the URL in the address bar - is that what you expect? What is the URL that can't be found? If you want to _see the URL change_ for testing, you can change it to a temporary redirect by adding the `R` flag.

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question is <i>"yes, exactly!"</i>. Just to clarify, what I am trying to accomplish is I have a result page for a dynamic search query on my prestashop website. I would like to assign a static page for it. But when I add the above rewrite rule in the htaccess file and enter the static url, it throws a 404 error. Thank you!

Comment: Just an update: adding the R flag made it work! but it is like a redirect now... can I "cloak" the redirected address? or am I getting everything wrong, what do you think...?

Comment: In that case the internal rewrite is "working" (without the `R` flag) but it sounds as if there might be something in the (Prestashop) code that is somehow dependent on the requested URL?! If, for instance the code was reliant on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] then it is likely to break. In order to "cloak" the URL you need an internal rewrite - as you were doing. Is there anything you need to enable in Prestashop for "friendly URLs"? There seems to be a lot of search results for "prestashop friendly url 404", but that maybe associated with creating friendly URLs across the whole site?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `[L]` flag from your rule. It prevents any other rule to apply but you need to passe this new route to Prestashop dispatcher.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    #Domain: test.example.com
    RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
    RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    # Images
    RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
    # [...]

# You need to put your condition here without the [L] flag
# And before the Dispatcher
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /de/suche?controller=$1&orderby=$2&orderway=$3&search_query=$4&submit_search=$5
# Your URL is then rewritten to Prestashop standard format
# and will be sent to the following Dispatcher.

    # Dispatcher
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```