# .htaccess file RewriteRules not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This question was answered numerous times on StackOverflow, and I really did search alot, but no answers seem to work for me. I've read [this article](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php), and found out why adding `Options +FollowSymlinks`, which is supposed to be necessary for RewriteRules to work doesn't work for me (my host has it automaticaly enabled on root level). So I removed it from my file, and tried if Rewrite engine even works. It does, but NONE of Regex stuff does. So I set up a test website at `http://example.com/hta.php?id=something&jmeno=somethingelse`, and added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^testdis/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) http://example.com/hta.php?id=$1&jmeno=$2 [NC]
```

This should make me be able to acces `http://example.com/testdis/5/s` and work like previously mentioned `http://example.com/hta.php?id=5&jmeno=s`, but it rewrites the adress to second, unwanted adress in URL tab.

So my question is: **Why doesn't my rewrite rule work, and how do I make it work?**

**EDIT**: Adding `[R]` parameter makes me able to type the "nice" url into my browser and upon presing enter it redirects me to "old/ugly" page with working values. However I want it to show the "nice" url.

**EDIT 2**: I was asked to post the code of my `hta.php` file. I don't think it anyhow matters, but here it is

```
<?php
  echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['jmeno'])){
  $jmeno = $_GET['jmeno'];
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <?php echo $id; ?>
  <br /><br />
  <?php echo $jmeno; ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It shouldn't really matter in this instance since you are rewriting to the same domain (Apache should strip the protocol/domain), but for internal rewrites you shouldn't really specify the protocol/domain. Just `/hta.php?id=$1&jmeno=$2`. Is the `L` flag required here? Although if it's the only directive it shouldn't matter. Try changing it to a temporary redirect (`R`) to make sure it is rewriting correctly. You have nothing else in .htaccess I assume?

Comment: What have you found that does work? Have you successfully used the `RewriteRule` directive in any form? "...and tried if Rewrite engine even works. It does, but" - In what way does it "work"?

Comment: @w3d I will try to change the flag and I will edit this comment, or write another. Yes, I have used `RewriteRule` sucesfully to redirect all .html files to .php files (read that in same guide I posted in question)

Comment: ...but you have nothing else in .htaccess for this latest test? (The order matters, particularly if you are mixing external redirects with internal rewrites.)

Comment: @w3d I only have `##comments` and `ErrorDocument 404 /docs/404.php` line, and the code I provided. I would like to ask....should I change `[NC]` to `[NC, R]`, or just `[R]`?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but it doesn't look like you need the `NC` flag. Do you really need this to be case-insensitive? Add the `L` flag as well (for good measure - you'd need it anyway if you add more directives.)

Comment: @w3d So I added `[R]` instead of `[NC]` and it is working, however it works the reverse way I want it to. I want the url to be shown as `http://example.com/testdis/5/s` for example, and it redirects me from it to `http://example.com/hta.php?id=5&jmeno=s` that way....which is propably right, because you wanted to test if it works at all.

Comment: Yes, that was just a test to make sure that you end up at the correct URL - which seems to be happening. So the directive is correct and seems to be working. What does your page do? Is it a simple test page? Is your page dependent on the requested URL? Sounds very similar to another question I was commenting on the other day... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254947/i-cannot-get-htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-work-with-my-prestashop-site

Comment: @w3d It's for testing purposes only, all it does is display the two parameters using `$_GET` value in the url. I tried adding multiple options in brackets (like `[NC, R]`) and that thrown 500 error. So while redirection works, I want the url to be "nice" as well. I think the problem could be with my provider, since my hosting doesn't say anything about .htaccess files on their website. Another reason could be wrong tag in brackets. I will find a list of tags so I can test it.

Comment: You should not have spaces between flags, it should be `[NC,R]`, not `[NC, R]` - that will cause a 500 error. (The space is a delimiter in Apache config files.) What other flags do you have? Can you post the actual .htaccess and contents of `hta.php`. There is no good reason why the internal rewrite is not working.

Comment: [It contains my actual website adress, and this is everything I have in my .htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/BR8bgyNw).
Thank you for telling me about multiple flags posting, didn't know about it being case sensitive inside brackets. I will edit my question with contents of my hta.php file.

Comment: Ok, I'm stumped. However, I would certainly change the `RewriteRule` substitution to be root-relative (as mentioned in the first comment). ie. `RewriteRule ^testdis/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) /hta.php?id=$1&jmeno=$2 [L]` would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you! This SOLVED the problem. Add it as answer, so I can mark you as solved. So for some example, my .htaccess file has problems with absolute paths. Thats good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an internal rewrite the `RewriteRule` substitution should not contain the scheme and hostname, so the following is preferable (and appears to solve the problem in this instance):

```
RewriteRule ^testdis/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+) /hta.php?id=$1&jmeno=$2 [L]
```

Normally, if you specify an absolute URL it will implicitly trigger an external redirect (as if you had explicitly used the `R` flag). Although, [the docs state](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) that if the hostname matches the current host (which as far as I know it does in this instance) the rewrite engine should automatically strip the scheme and hostname from the substitution.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

However, in my experience this does not appear to happen, an absolute URL in the substitution *always* results in an external redirect, regardless of the hostname. (?)

Comment: I forgot to edit out the "404 error". It was caused because I tested it wrong, providing a letter instead of number into the first parameter. Will edit it out.